# Spaces in Associative Array Keys while looping through multiple arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, associative-array

I am having a bit of trouble while looping through multiple associative arrays in bash.

Here is the code I'm running: (stripped of the actual information)

```
arrays=("arrayone" "arraytwo")
declare -A arrayone=(["one"]=1 ["two"]=2)
declare -A arraytwo=(["text with spaces"]=value ["more text with spaces"]=differentvalue)
for array in ${arrays[*]} 
 do 
 for key in $(eval echo $\{'!'$array[@]\})   
       do 
       echo "$key"
       done
 done
```

This works perfectly fine until I run into a key value that has spaces in it. No matter what I do, I cannot get items with spaces to be treated correctly.

I would appreciate any ideas you have on how to get this working.
If there is, a better way to do this, I'd be happy to hear it. I don't mind scratching this and starting over. It's just the best I've been able to come up with so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Quoted expansion of `[@]` is needed to preserve spaces.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but I can't figure out how to do it in this particular instance. (It messes with my eval command) I've tried various combinations of double and single-quotes with backslashes, etc. and googled this to death already. Two hours later, I'm here.

Comment: Hm... true, `$()` is going to throw that away even if you get the internal expansion right. I don't think you can do it this way. You probably need to write a function for the inner loop and pass it `$array[@]` and do the indirect expansion in the function. Like `isSubset` from [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays#indirection).

Comment: Thanks, I think I can get somewhere with that.

Comment: Typically, to iterate over the *values* of an array where the name is dynamic, you'd need a placeholder var for the indirect expansion: `tmp="${array}[@]"; for elem in "${!tmp}"; ...` -- however, using that idiom, you can't iterate over the *keys*: this does not work: `tmp='!'"${array}[@]"; for key in "${!tmp}"; ...` -- this `${!tmp}` expands to nothing. You may be reduced to parsing the output of `declare -p "$array"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash added the [nameref attribute](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters-1) in 4.3. It allows you to make a name specifically a reference to another. In your case, you would do

```
declare -A assoc_one=(["one"]=1 ["two"]=2)
declare -A assoc_two=(["text with spaces"]=value ["more text with spaces"]=differentvalue)
declare -n array # Make it a nameref
for array in "${!assoc_@}"; do 
    for key in "${!array[@]}"; do
        echo "'$key'"
    done
done
```

and you get

```
'one'
'two'
'text with spaces'
'more text with spaces'
```

Names were changed to protect the idioms. I mean, I changed the array names so I could do `"${!assoc_@}"` without making `array` a special case.

Comment: "Names were changed to protect the idioms" was worth an up-vote in its own right. Good to know that you can _defer_ binding a nameref, and even _rebind iteratively_ when using a `declare -n` variable as a `for` control variable.

Comment: @mklement0 what's more interesting is that I can't seem to rebind manually inside a while loop. This could lead to a followup SO question if I have time to do some research.

Comment: Yes, the `for` behavior is special (mentioned in the man page). To do it in a `while` loop, move the `declare -n` statement _inside_ the loop; note that you _must_ bind as part of the `declare -n` statement for this to work; e.g., `while ...; do declare -n nameref=...; done`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a way to do this, but I wasn't getting anywhere. This was what I needed.